# How to show that geodesic in polar coordinates satisfies the great circle equation in cartesian

Tags: calculus-of-variations, geodesic

I've shown using Euler-Lagrange equation that the shortest path between two points on a unit sphere is
$$\phi = -\arcsin\left(\frac{\cot \theta}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{c_1^2}-1}}\right) + c_2$$

Now, I need to show that $\phi$ satisfies $$x\sin(c_2) + y\cos(c_2) - \frac{z}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{c_1^2}-1}} = 0$$
where $x=\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)$, $y=\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$ and $z=\cos(\theta)$ as usual on the unit sphere with $R=1$.

I did the following:
$$\sin(\phi - c_2) = \frac{-\cot(\theta)}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{c_1^2}-1}}$$
$$\sin(\phi)\cos(c_2) - \cos(\phi)\sin(c_2) = \frac{-\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)\sqrt{\frac{1}{c_1^2}-1}}$$
$$\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\cos(c_2) - \sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)\sin(c_2) = \frac{-\cos(\theta)}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{c_1^2}-1}}$$

$$y\cos(c_2) -x\sin(c_2) +\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{c_1^2}-1}} = 0$$
Problem is that I'm missing a minus sign before $y\cos(c_2)$ and I can't find where I went wrong.

Thanks

Comment: I think it's perfect. Are you sure that the expression for $\phi$ is correct? Maybe the provided answer is wrong

Comment: Unfortunately yes, I'm certain regarding the expression and the expected answer. It's possible that the expected answer is wrong.

Comment: Im sure that the expected answer is wrong